# How can I break out of a cycle on any line I want in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, break

I want to immediately terminate a cycle based on some kind of external input (int, string or whatever), but I don't know when it's coming, is there some kind of asynchronous method in java to act in the exact moment a specific input arrives?

Example more or less of what I want to do:

```
public void run(){
    while(/*condition*/){

        //let's say it receives a String more times like this:
        String s = inSocket.readLine();

        // and in the bottom, I could put an if:
        if(s.equals("stop")){
        break;
        }
    }

// here some other code that I still want to execute, exiting the cycle

}
```

In this case, the cycle stops only at that particular line where I wrote `break`; I want it to be able to break out immediately, any time the received string is "stop", but I don't know when that will be, as i receive multiple strings during execution.

Second example(more clear):

```
while(true){
    /*line 0*/ String A = inSocket.readLine();
    /*line 1*/
    /*line 2*/ String B = inSocket.readLine();
    /*line 3*/
    /*line 4*/ String C = inSocket.readLine();
    /*line 5*/
    /*line 6*/ String D = inSocket.readLine();
    /*line 7*/

     if(/*A or B or C or D is "stop" */ ){
    /*line 10*/ break;
        }
}
```

Any of the previous strings can be `stop`, my problem is that `break` will always be executed at line 10. 
I want to execute it *immediately* after one of those strings is `stop`, and I do not know which one of the four strings will be `stop`.

I'm wondering if java has some method that can do a `break` in lines 1,3,5,7 just by telling it "beware of `stop` "; aside the solution of putting an `if` after every single readLine.

Comment: Why don't you do `while(!s.equals("stop")){ if(s.equals("stop")){} else {}  } ` ?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you want to stop your code from running at some arbitrary point in the method.

You could use a thread with a volatile boolean to indicate that the thread should stop, then have plenty of break points to monitor this boolean. But I don't think it's possible or desirable to do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MaxAlexander yea I'm not a genius so i wanted to make sure about that; the only way to do it would be to put a lot of ifs then

Comment: @PhillAlexakis it happens that I have to read  `s` two times in a row; if the first is "stop" then I still have to read the second instead of exiting immediately, if I wrote the code inside  `else `

Comment: Why don't you 1.`read`  2.`while condition` 3.`read at end of while` ?

Comment: because it's a thread and it might be executed parallel with another one?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis I'm making a sort of a small game, while is a complete player's turn and the player has to give around 8-10 inputs per turn; I want to make him able to quit the game anytime if he writes "quit" on command line. While ended means end of the game, i need to give out some last messages

Comment: i don't understand what you `cant` do..

Answer (score 1):

First of all on your question you don't provide much information about the `asynchronous` task you are trying to create.

My logic says this: put the `s.equals("stop")` at the `while` condition and check for the `string` again in the end like so:

```java
String s = inSocket.readLine();

while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {

 if ( /*Your condition in while loop*/ ) {

 } else{
     //break; 
 }

  s = inSocket.readLine(); //read again
}
```

I'm not sure if i've completed understood your issue, does this work for you?

This is an alternative based on your exact example

```java
String s = inSocket.readLine();
while ( /*Condition*/ ) {

if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
  break;
 }

 //do your stuff here

  s = inSocket.readLine()
 //read again, if it's stop, will quit.
}
```

Comment: Quite a few issues with this. It won't compile, since you declare 2 local variables with the same name. Not sure if you meant to do `s = inSocket.readLine();` (reassign existing variable, rather than create a new local variable), but even with that, `while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))` should probably be `while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))`, because with what you wrote, the loop will only execute if the user types in "stop", which is backwards.

Comment: Your thinking is right, though: the logic for whether there loop should stop or not would be better fit defined in the conditional section of the loop. You'll need to nest the assignment: `while (!(s = inSocket.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))` - but as you can see, this isn't easily readable at first glance.

Comment: i added a second example that should be more clear; my problem is that this can work for only one string if I'm correct, but as i said inside the while's body i need to have together more readLines, they must be all together inside the body I can't separate them

Comment: yes i was missing a `!` in  `while(!equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))` , although my first example as it is now , should be the same with yours

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. In fact, you could just do

```
while(true) {
    String s = inSocket.readLine();

    if(s.equals("stop")) {
        break;
    }

    // Use the value, since it was not "stop"
}

// Execute other code
```

Notice how I put the check at the beginning of the top, not the bottom.

If you're not a fan of `while(true)` loops, the "right" way to do this would to specify the breaking condition when you define the loop:

```
String s;
while(!(s = inStream.readLine()).equals("stop")) {
    // Will not execute/continue running if user entered "stop"
}

// Execute other code
```

The loop should iterate 1 time every time the user enters input. This means all input will be checked for "stop", assuming you don't call `readLine()` again within the loop.

Comment: what's the difference between that and my example?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis Your code shows `while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))`. Even if you fixed that, my 2nd approach is obviously different from yours.. Even the first is different, with only 1 `readLine` call, not 2. How are you going to ask "What's the difference" when not only do I tell the OP he was right (instead of suggesting he needed a new structure, like your answer suggests), but I post working code & give an alternative that doesn't come close to matching your example? Huge difference between this and your example. Seems as if your answer just left him with more questions.

Comment: i completely understand what you are saying, sure it's better `inline` , but the output is the same

Comment: @PhillAlexakis It wasn't the same output as your first example (until you changed it). Even if it was right at first (which it wasn't), both of my suggestions were cleaner than both of yours; readability matters. You can't post bugged code, then try to question why other people are giving answers to compete with yours.. Your code was bugged, and even after the fix, it's not logically sound. You don't need the `if` to check the condition AGAIN (the whole "*Your condition in while loop*"). You didn't test your answer, you didn't walk through it to see if it made sense. Why question my answer?